# Non-isolated singularity of $\frac{1}{z^2(1+e^{1/z})}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I was doing a practice question and the solution provided indicated that the function $$\frac{1}{z^2(1+e^{1/z})}$$ Had an non-isolated singularity at the origin. If there was a singularity there I can see why it is non-isolated but I am not convinced there is even a singularity there. This is because the denominator seems to go to $\infty$ as $z\rightarrow 0$. Who is right me or the answer provided, please can you explain either way.

Comment: Let $z$ approach $0$ a) through negative real numbers, and b) through purely imaginary numbers.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you, does this still count as a singularity if in some directions it tends to $\infty$ and in others it tends to $0$, and does it have a special name or anything?

Comment: It seems you confuse the point of singularity with the value of the function in such a point. There is no reason this value be zero necessarily.

Comment: We call such a singularity an **essential** singularity (as opposed to a removable singularity or a pole).

Comment: The function isn't analytic in any neighbourhood of $0$ (and $0$ lies in the closure of its domain), so $0$ is a singularity. It's a non-isolated singularity. Some authors subsume non-isolated singularities under essential singularities, others don't.

Comment: No, the denominator doesn't go to infinity. When $z$ is near zero $1/z$ will take on arbitrary large positive and negative values and therefore $e^{1/z}$ will take both large and small values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a non-isolated singularity. The $1+e^{1/z}$ term will be zero whenever $e^{1/z} = -1$.

Now the exponential function along the imaginary axis is $e^{j\phi} = \cos\phi + j\sin\phi$ and therefore $e^{j(2n+1)\pi} = -1$. So if $z_n=1/(j(2n+1)\pi)$ we have that $1+e^{1/z}=0$ and such can be found arbitrarily near the origin. That is we have singularities at $z_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n = 0$.

The concept of singularity is maybe not so simple to define as there are some various situations that should be covered - they are not only poles. The cases are (ordered from least severe to most severe case)

- Removable singularity: a case where you can define a value in the point that makes the singularity go away, for example $z/z$ at origin.
- Pole: a singularity that can be handled by multiplying with a polynomial, for example $1/z$ at the origin. This case means that the limit will be $\infty$.
- Essential singularity: an isolated singularity that is not able to be handled by multiplying with polynomial, $e^{1/z}$ is of this kind, they are characterized by the Laurent series having infinite number of negative terms.
- Non-isolated singularity: a situation when you have a sequence of singularities $z_n$ and a limit of this $z = \lim z_n$, your function is an example of this. Since it's non-isolated you can't have a laurent series around (just) that singularity.

The two last cases will have that the function will oscillate wildly near the singularity instead of going to infinity.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here is a plot of $|f(z)|$ in the region $\Re(z), \Im(z) \in [-1/b, 1/b]$ for $b > 1$.  Note that the vertical axis is automatically rescaled in this animation, so as we "zoom" into a neighborhood of $0$, the height that is being plotted varies somewhat.  We can clearly see that the singularity at $z = 0$ is not isolated owing to a progression of singularities along the imaginary axis.

[image]

Comment: This is fascinating. Can you share how you drew this? What software did you use? Any way you can share your code?

Comment: @David it’s probably mathematica